# How to add "../" into a PHP echo img src

Tags: php, mysql, image, echo

In my code I show some images in this way:

```
   ...
     <?php echo '<img src="' .$imageone. '" alt="" /> '?></a></div>
     <?php echo '<img src="' .$imagetwo. '" alt="" /> '?></a></div>
   ...
```

where $imageone, $imagetwo have path from Mysql database

```
e.g.
$imagesone = "images/exposition/02-05-2017-11-28-00-foto 2_b.JPG";
```

This code is working in the same place where I have my images folder, but now I need to put the same code in a subfolder page and I'd like to use the same image.
So, I need to put dinamically "../" before my varible, something like this:

```
...
     <?php echo '<img src="../' .$imageone. '" alt="" /> '?></a></div>
     <?php echo '<img src="../' .$imagetwo. '" alt="" /> '?></a></div>
   ...
```

but it's not working.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT** This is my solution:

```
 if ($images1 != ""){

    $imageone = "../".$images1;

}

if ($images2 != ""){

    $imagetwo = "../".$images2;

}
```

in this way I fixed my code and it's working!

Comment: *How* is it not working?

Comment: Do `ctrl+u`(on Windows) or `cmd+u`(on Mac) to see the source code, and check whether the URLs are correct or not.

Comment: how it's not working? any error. seems that it need to be worked

Comment: See [Absolute vs relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: I tried to see the source code, but there isn't "../" before the path from my database

Comment: @James69  There is a TYPO mistake in your code `$imagesone !== $imageone` (the two variable names are different)

Comment: Thanks everybody! I edited my post with a solution that I found. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using double quotation marks after `src`, you can just write down `<img src="../$imageone" alt="" />`
There's no need to use simple quotation marks to write the variable because the double quotation marks gets the variable number.